# How do I change the background color of the Gesture bar of my Flutter app

Tags: flutter, user-interface

How do I change the background color of the Gesture bar of my Flutter app. the bottom where the gesture bar is has a white background, I'd like to make it match the bottom navbar instead.

[image: the bottom where the gesture bar is has a white background, I'd like to make it match the bottom navbar instead]

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: please provide code for above scenario.